# How to dynamically add multiple array-list in a List

Tags: android, list, listview, arraylist, android-custom-view

I want to add multiple array-list in a list and display in list-view using custom adapter with section. i have tried here is my code i tried

```
   for (int i=0;i<mModelJsoncatData.size();i++){
                if (mModelJsoncatData.get(i).getCatName().equals("Eating")) {
                    ListAll.add(new String(mModelJsoncatData.get(i).getCatName()));
                    ListAll.addAll(mModelJsonEating);
                }
                if (mModelJsoncatData.get(i).getCatName().equals("Feeling")) {
                    ListAll.add(new String(mModelJsoncatData.get(i).getCatName()));
                    ListAll.addAll(mModelJsonFeeling);
                }
                if (mModelJsoncatData.get(i).getCatName().equals("Listening to")) {
                    ListAll.add(new String(mModelJsoncatData.get(i).getCatName()));
                    ListAll.addAll(mModelJsonListening);
                }
                if (mModelJsoncatData.get(i).getCatName().equals("Watching")) {
                    ListAll.add(new String(mModelJsoncatData.get(i).getCatName()));
                    ListAll.addAll(mModelJsonWatching);
                }
            }
MAdapter adapter=new MAdapter(this,ListAll);
listview1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

but its not showing the desired results
any suggestions or help needed

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a list of lists!

```
List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    lists.add(list);
    // Use the list further...
}
```

**To Merge 3 arraylist to one**

```
List<String> combined = new ArrayList<String>();
combined.addAll(firstArrayList);
combined.addAll(secondArrayList);
combined.addAll(thirdArrayList);
```

Reference :-https://stackoverflow.com/a/8625256/7795876

Comment: i want to add multiple array-lists in a  list and want to display in  listview

Comment: i have 5 array list and with different model classes and i want to display these in a single list view with section header one after another

Comment: not worked because i have different data types in each array list and  now idea about sections